# Loading data from MySQL and populating dropdown select with jQuery Mobile, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile

I am developing a PhoneGap application that gets some information from MySQL Database. I am struggling when I try to open a HTML page that contains two select input that need to be populated on page load, each one with data from two different tables. I don't why, but they are not getting populated. Please, any help will be very welcome.

HTML CODE

```
<div data-role="content">
  <p></p>
  <form id="cname" align="left" action="post" data-ajax="false" >
    <label for "id">Employee's Name:</label><br/>
    <select name="id" id="id"></select><br/>
    <label for "job_id">Job's Name:</label><br/>
    <select name="job_id" id="job_id"></select><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="latitued" id="latitued" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="goo_map_api" id="goo_map_api" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Clock-In" id="enviar_in" data-inline="true">
  </form>
</div
```

Jquery Script both SELECTS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var items="";
  $.getJSON("get_emp.php",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.fullName+"</option>";
    });
    $("#id").html(items); 
  });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var items="";
  $.getJSON("get_job.php",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.job_name+"</option>";
    });
    $("#job_id").html(items); 
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP file get_emp.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$q = "select id, fullName from employees";
$sql = $mysqli->query($q);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

PHP file get_job.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$q = "select id, job_name from jobs";
$sql = $mysqli->query($q);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

One more time, I appreciate your time taking a look at this code trying to give me a hand.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks good. Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks @wumm. No, I don't. I did the apk and tested on my phone. I could do login tests but when I reach this point, the page cannot load the information from database and populate my select inputs.

Comment: Jquery mobile doesn't fire document ready as expected, search it on stack. Also, could you not just use PHP to populate them?

Comment: I would love do not use PHP to populate those inputs, but, how can I access a MySQL and retrieve the data if not with PHP scripts @scrowler?

Comment: Just put your PHP code into your HTML code and instead of populating an array, output the results as `<option>`s

Comment: this won't work for HTML5 . How the PHP script will take effect within my HTML5 page? Remember that this is a mobile application. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

At first glimpse the code looks all right. What did you have in the console? Is all the json data there? Otherwise try

```
$.each(data,function(index,item) 
{
    $('<option>').val(item.id).html(item.job_name).appendTo("#job_id");
});
```

Updates:
can you please try adding

> error_log(print_r($data,1));

before

> echo json_encode($data);

in get_emp.php and check the php_error.log to see if the data is populated on the server side when you load the page

Comment: Thanks @aaryy but still couldn't get data from the database.

Comment: My application is being developed at Dreamweaver and after insert the line that you suggest, I could see the SELECTS loaded using the LIVE option of Dreamweaver. When I make the apk using the Adobe PhoneGap, before publish it, I install the app in my phone using the QR Code just to test it. I can make login perfectly, what makes me believe that the interaction with database is working ok, but when I access the pages that are supposed to be loaded with the data nothing is populated.

Comment: Did you see the error logs generated by that error_log statement? Does it have an array containing the data from the database as you expected?

Comment: No error has been reported! Like I said. The select is loaded when I simulate the app, but once is installed in the phone, doesn't load anything. I did a test. I put an alert msg within my jquery structure, just after the SELECT is loaded. It pops up when simulating it but when is in the phone, nothing happens. Looks like the script are not read.

Comment: Not necessarily errors, it is supposed to contain an array in the form of array{ array {0 =>'blabla', 'id' => 'blabla', 1 => 'blabla', 'fullName' => 'blabla'},array {0 =>'blabla', 'id' => 'blabla', 1 => 'blabla', 'fullName' => 'blabla'} }. I believe what you said that the select query is executed, just want to make sure the query result is all right

Comment: Hey! @aaryy! I just figured out that my mistake was misplacing the scripts in the page. I created one js and put them all inside. Now works very good

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay to me. Have you set the correct header?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh A these are the headers that I am using header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header("access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("access-control-allow-credentials: true");
header("access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, *");
header("Content-type: application/json");

Answer (score 0):

I think it has todo with timing between DOM ready and executing the Jquery script.

In this case your script executes before the DOM is ready. If some objects you are refering to, arent ready yet in the DOM, thus JQuery cant find the object, then JQuery simply stops executing.